# Angular 6 highlight issue

Tags: angular

when i'm installing the highlight command and compile the application it return error.

command:

```
npm install ngx-highlight
```

app module ts:

```
import { HighlightModule } from 'ngx-highlight/highlight.module';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HighlightModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

[image: Error screenshot here]

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code or error messages, post them as text instead.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `import { HighlightModule } from 'ngx-highlightjs';`?

Comment: i'm using ngx-highlight not ngx-highlightjs

Comment: According to docs, it has to be `import { HighlightModule } from 'ngx-highlight/fill-highlight.module'` actually.

Comment: but `fill-highlight.module` not found in my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the doc, it says 'fill-highlight.module'. Try deleting node-modules and re-run 'npm install'.

```
import { HighlightModule } from 'ngx-highlight/fill-highlight.module';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [....],
    imports: [
        ....
        HighlightModule,
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: []
})

export class AppModule { }
```